# Area Route Problem in Netcore 3.1, invalid routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem with area

in netcore 3.1, I add my endpoint on startup.cs,

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            //   endpoints.MapControllers();

            //endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            //      name: "default",
            //      pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
               name: "default",
               pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
```

add the service

```
    services.AddControllersWithViews();//.AddNewtonsoftJson(); ;
        services.AddRazorPages();
```

but it's routing on this way, what obviously doesn't work

```
 controller/action?area=area
```

Example

```
 Patients/Create?area=Medical
```

This is the way than I call it (by legacy purpose)

```
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("Create", "Patients", new { area = "Medicals" })">
New Patient</a>
```

I try in the classic way for netcore and trowme the same route

```
    <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Patients" asp-area="Medicals">
New Patient</a>
```

I have the Package **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation 3.1.9** Installed, than use to be the main problem with razor

Comment: Have a look at [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/expanding-razor-view-location-and-sub-areas-in-asp-net-core/). It has a working example. I've never done custom routing like this, but judging by your code I could say 2 things: 1) Don't keep the same name `default`. 2) Move your custom router above the default router

Comment: Thanks, i will try it, the rare it's than on new project it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution it's so stupid, the order for the area configuration it' important, so, area need to be set first

```
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
           name: "default",
           pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```